# Docker - parent image execution fails due to missing root access

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The parent image I am using seems to require root access to run its `ENTRYPOINT` instruction.

In my `Dockerfile` I need to run my own container (executable) with normal user at the end. How do I switch back and forth between users here?

Psuedo Dockerfile:

```
FROM parentrepo/parentimg # its Dockerfile probably has ENTRYPOINT at the end which requires root access
#my app specific instructions
WORKDIR ..
RUN mkdir ..
COPY ..
RUN tar ..
EXPOSE 9000
USER nir # HEre i want to switch user to nir
WORKDIR ${myhome}
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./start"]
```

Running above fails as parent requires sudo access. if I don't do `USER nir` then my process starts as root user which i don't want. Does the parent Dockerfile need to have `USER root` here ?

Also, Is there any document that describe how docker `Build` execute instructions at high level? . How it interacts with hierarchies of parent Dockerfiles. Looks like it imports instructions from parent docker files; creates one docker file. Does it reorder instruction in anyway?

ANd what happens at runtime which executing via `docker run` ? I know `RUN` command is used at build time while `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` executed at runtime but it still doesn't explain whole picture and sequences from build otherwise it would have been clear what I need to do.

Comment: You need to set your own ENTRYPOINT to override the parent one.

Comment: wouldn't it skip parents ENTRYPOINT then? `Only the last ENTRYPOINT instruction in the Dockerfile will have an effect.` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: Yes it would. You can't add your own command to run, docker starts exactly one process. If the parents entrypoint does something important you may need to set everything up yourself in your start script.

Comment: so i can not have a container which will have lets say apache http and my own service running if apache http were to be a parent image? now that i think of it that;s probably point of containerization.  do you know any good document that explain the build/execution process? when exactly does parent entry point gets called? what are the sequence of execution etc

Comment: Docker starts 1 process but that process could be a process manager i.e. supervisord which itself starts n number of processes, ref. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ - i have to disagree @tkausl.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a user `nir` inside that image and also give appropriate ownership and rights to execute that `./start` script.

Here is what I tried and it worked.

- Created a `Dockerfile` with following contents

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /
#RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash nir <= (This will work for non-alpine images)
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S nir -G appgroup
COPY . /
RUN chown nir:appgroup /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
USER nir
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/start.sh"]
```

- Contents of `start.sh` script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello" > /tmp/abc.txt
sleep 100
exec "$@"
```

- Build and run the container.

```
$ docker run -itd  t:t .
$ docker run -itd  t:t
$ docker exec -it de11dbffb2ca sh
/ $ ls /tmp/abc.txt
/tmp/abc.txt
/ $ cat /tmp/abc.txt
hello
/ $ ls -ltrh /tmp/
total 4K
-rw-r--r--    1 nir      appgroup       6 Jun 21 04:35 abc.txt
/ $
```

As you can see the script `start.sh` is successfully executed by user `nir`. Here we just created appropriate user using `adduser` for alpine based image (or use useradd for non-alpine images). Given appropriate permission to the script using `chown` and `chmod`.

Hope this helps, let me know.